# How to modify email Transactional template?

Tags: magento-1.8, email

I need an shipping method condition in transaction email.
It has to display 1 message for ShippingMethodA and no message for ShippingMethodB.

Im trying to do it by transactional email conditions:

```
{{if  order.getShippingMethod() == flatrate2_flatrate2}}
<p><span>The tracking number is: {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}} Your order can be tracked here: <a href="http://www.trackitonline.ru/">http://www.trackitonline.ru/</a></span></p>
{{/if}}
```

or with doublequotes:

```
{{if  order.getShippingMethod() == "flatrate2_flatrate2"}}
```

but the condition is always true and displays same message for all shipping methods.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{if}}` directives do not support a comparison.
Just a simple expression that evaluates to true/false.

So `{{if something}}...` is OK..
`{{if something == something_else}}...` does not work.

You will need to rewrite the method that sends the e-mail and add an other variable to the template.

So you need to modify `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` and change this:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'order'        => $this,
    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
));
```

To

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'order'        => $this,
    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
    'is_flatrate'  => $this->getShippingMethod() == 'flatrate2_flatrate2'
));
```

Then you can use in your template this:

```
{{if is_flatrate}} 
...
{{else}}
..
{{/if}}
```